# Symfony 2 InvalidArgumentException when creating a new service

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create my first service in a symfony 2 application and I get this error :

```
InvalidArgumentException: There is no extension able to load the
configuration for "my_app.myservice" (in
/path/to/src/MyApp/MyBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/services.yml).
Looked for namespace "my_app.myservice", found none.
```

It seems there's a problem in my configuration but I don't see what it is.

Here's my **services.yml**

```
services:
my_app.myservice:
    class: MyApp\MyBundle\Service\MyService
```

And my service looks like this

```
<?php
namespace MyApp\MyBundle\Service;

class MyService
{
    public function run()
    {
        echo "hello world";
    }
}
```

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be sure - do you have proper indentation in the services.yml?

It should be:

```
services:
  my_app.myservice:
    class: MyApp\MyBundle\Service\MyService
```

not:

```
services:
my_app.myservice:
  class: MyApp\MyBundle\Service\MyService
```

Comment: That's it !! Arf ! It was so obvious and simple. I can't believe I've waste so much time on something like this. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any argument in your service's constructor ?

For example i pass the logger in all my services.

it's result that i have to pass it in my service.yml

---

`service.yml`

```
services:
    blog:
        class:Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Service\BlogService
        arguments: [@logger]
        tags:
            - { name: monolog.logger, channel: blog}
```

`BlogService`

```
public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger){
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

Comment: Nope I don't have any argument in the constructor. In fact I didn't have any constructor at all in the service. I tryed to add one but it doesn't work any better.